# Is it possible to capture the console screen under Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, delphi, console, components

I want to make a GUI Windows application that can run console applications. When this happens, the console window should not be shown. Instead its content should be shown in a visual component (memo/richedit). This component should show exactly the same content which would appear in the console window, even the color of the text and its background should be displayed. So this visual component should work exactly as a console window. I know that the standard output can be captured but many console applications do not use it. Is it possible to capture the output of a console application this way? Are there Windows API calls that can handle this?

I use Delphi XE2 but C# code would also be helpful.

Comment: "_many console applications do not use it_" - please link to a few examples where it can be reconstructed that capturing their STDOUT (or STDERR) fails thru `ReadFile()` of a pipe.

Comment: Ffmpeg, for example does not use the standard output. If you redirect it to a file, nothing will be written to it. These type of applications don't just write lines to the output but they sometimes overwrite something that was written previously.

Comment: It is possible to create a normal console window and then embed it as a child on your form. I don't know if this is a bad idea, but I just tried it and it kind of works.

Comment: I guess a proper formulation is: how can one capture i.e. [`SetConsoleCursorPosition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) of a console application?

Comment: Yes. But I also doubt that ffmpeg uses the standard write functions because if you redirect its output to a text file, it will be empty.

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand: Thank you! However the best solution would be a graphic memo/richedit component which works exactly as a console window.

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand: Can you tell me exactly how did you do this child console window embedding in Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

There is a ready-to-run component on GitHub: [DosCommand](https://github.com/TurboPack/DOSCommand)

The Demo shows two ways how to do what you describe.

I am not sure if it works for older versions like XE2, but at least you can give it a try.

Comment: It seems to me that this component only redirects the standard output/input. My problem is that many console applications do not use it to display text. Maybe they write directly to the screen memory or something like that.

Comment: I wonder how they could do that. Do you have an example of such an application?

Comment: ffmpeg is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the console mode program with stdout redirection to a pipe that your Delphi program will create. Your Delphi program can read the pipe to get the console mode program output and do whatever it needs to. By the way, this works not only with Delphi but also with any language able to create pipe and run program with I/O redirection.

If you need Delphi code to do that, have a look at [this reference](http://francois-piette.blogspot.com/2013/04/inter-process-communication-using-pipes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally you would call `CreateProcess` with stdin/stdout set to pipes you created. This should work for most programs but not for anything that uses a ncurses style "GUI" and you also lose the color information. An example can be found [on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

Windows 10 (1809?) added support for [pseudoconsoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/pseudoconsoles). This is used by the new Terminal application and is your best bet for full console compatibility.

The last alternative is to inject into the child process and hook `WriteFile`, `ReadFile` and all the console functions but this is ugly and error-prone.